# chai subset with unknown array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, chai

I have a complex JSON object I want to test.
Is there a way to get this to work in chai subset, or an alternative plugin where this test can pass.

```
var result = {
  present: 'Yes',
  notPresent: 'No',
  examples: ['sam','joe'],
  nestedThing: {
    nestedAttr: 1,
  }
};

var expected = {
  present: 'Yes',
  nestedThing: {
    nestedAttr: 1,
  }
  examples: [],
}

chai.expect(result).to.containSubset(expected);
```

I want to assert that `examples` is an array, but I don't care what (if any) items are in the array.

Bonus points if I can assert it has at least 1 item, but I think that's unlikely.

**EDIT**

I'm fine to restructure the `expected` a little if it will allow it to work. eg

```
var expected = {
  ...
  examples: chai.matcher.isArray(),
}
```

Comment: Does include cannot accommodate your need ?

Comment: doesn't seem like there's any existing plugin that has the specific test you seek, but you could always write your own custom plugin

Comment: I don't think include will work for more complex matching with nested objects. I've updated the example to illustrate a little more clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up going with chai-shallow-deep-equal which does support this behaviour. (Though not checking the lenght of the array, but that was a long shot).

Example here: https://runkit.com/chrisjensen/subset-match-empty-array

I also [created a fork](https://github.com/raisely/chai-shallow-deep-equal) so that it would show a diff when the match failed. **UPDATE** that fork has been accepted into chai-shallow-deep-equal

```
var chai = require("chai"); // chai is a peer dependency. 
var chaiShallowDeepEqual = require("chai-shallow-deep-equal")

chai.use(chaiShallowDeepEqual);

var result = {
  present: 'Yes',
  notPresent: 'No',
  examples: ['sam','joe'],
  nestedThing: {
    nestedAttr: 1,
  }
};

var expected = {
  present: 'Yes',
  nestedThing: {
    nestedAttr: 1,
  },
  examples: [],
}

chai.expect(result).to.shallowDeepEqual(expected);
```